# Test to verify if the dependency registered correctly in windsor

Tags: c#, moq, castle-windsor

I have a class which inherited from IWindsorInstaller. I use this class to install/register the dependencies. Now I want to write tests for this class.

I register in the container a dependency with parameter. Like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IXService>().ImplementedBy<XService>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("operationY", "OperationY")).LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

Now in my Unit-Test, I want to verify if it is registered correctly. Something like this:

```
_containerMock.Verify(f=>f.Register(It.IsAny<ComponentRegistration<IXService>>().ImplementedBy<XService>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("operationY", "OperationY")).LifestyleSingleton()),Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

I don't have any idea, what should I do?
Thanks in advance, Mo.

Comment: The easiest way is to resolve it from the container...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RB. But what do you mean?

Comment: I've posted an answer to describe more fully what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test is not there to prove that the container has a registration for a given service.

It's to prove that the container can resolve that service (the fact that a registration exists is an implementation detail).

So, in your unit test, just attempt to resolve your service and verify it's what you are looking for, e.g:

```
public void UnitTest_Prove_That_Service_Can_Be_Created() 
{
    var sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    var container = sut.GetContainer();
    var service = container.Resolve<IXService>();

    // Prove the IXService resolves to an XService - i.e. the registration
    // has the correct mapping.
    Assert.Type<XService>(service);
}
```

Additionally, you might want to prove it's a singleton:

```
public void UnitTest_Prove_That_Service_Is_A_Singleton() 
{
    var sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    var container = sut.GetContainer();
    var service1 = container.Resolve<IXService>();
    var service2 = container.Resolve<IXService>();

    // Prove you got the same service back each time - i.e. it's a singleton
    Assert.Equals(service1, service2);
}
```

### EDIT

The fact that the SUT is an `IWindsorInstaller` doesn't really change my answer. Just tweak the unit test slightly:

```
public void UnitTest_Prove_That_Service_Can_Be_Created() 
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Install(new SystemUnderTest());
    var service = container.Resolve<IXService>();

    // Prove the IXService resolves to an XService - i.e. the registration
    // has the correct mapping.
    Assert.Type<XService>(service);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I think that I should add that: my Sut is a class that implements Install method of **_IWindsorInstaller_**.

Comment: @MoMahdiM Unless I've misunderstood you, that doesn't really change my answer - please see my edit.

Comment: you are right. But I still have a question/problem. This component (XService) is dependent on component (OperationY) and when I try to resolve it, I receive this:
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: 'Can't create component 'XService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

Comment: Well - doesn’t that indicate that the unit test has identified a bug in your Installer (ie it is not self contained)? Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. It's a chain of Dependencies. XService depends on OperationY. It means that I should first resolve operationY then I should try to Resolve XService?

Comment: Something like this here: http://www.longest.io/2015/04/24/autowiring-chain-composite-decorator-in-windsor.html